# Add Chi test to plot_stackfrq in R

Tags: r

I need to add to the plot_stackfrq in R the Chi test, I didn't see any parameter of the function that accepts chi.test or similar.
This is my code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
homes2 <- homes %>% mutate(rn = rowid(Educ_level)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Educ_level, values_from = Insurance)

plot_stackfrq(homes2[,c("High Scholl","College","Elementary")], 
              geom.colors = c("YlOrBr"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve it with plot_xtab, this did show me Chi test as I needed.

```
plot_xtab(homes2$Educ_label, homes2$Insurance, bar.pos = "stack", show.total = FALSE, margin = "row", coord.flip = TRUE, show.n = FALSE, show.summary = TRUE,
geom.colors = c("YlOrBr"))
```